# Popen not responding to kill

Tags: python, bash, raspberry-pi

Environment: Raspberry Pi Wheezy

I have a python program that uses Popen to call another python program

```
from subprocess import *

oJob = Popen('sudo python mypgm.py',shell=True)
```

Another menu option is supposed to end the job immediately

```
oJob.kill()
```

but the job is still running??

Comment: In addition to the (valid/correct) point made by others that `shell=True` is evil, you can't kill a job you don't own, and `sudo` makes the job owned by root, not yourself.

Comment: if do a chgmod +x on my python pgm i get an error message about wiringPi needs sudo to use wiringPiSetup

Comment: That you need `sudo` doesn't stop it from making you unable to signal processes so elevated -- as such, I don't really know what your comment above is intended to accomplish. Now, you could `sudo kill ${pid}`, for the process ID of `oJob`, such that your kill has escalated privileges as well, _or_ you could run the whole program under `sudo`, thus already having escalated privileges for both the launch _and_ the kill, thus avoiding to need to use `sudo` again.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a creation flag arg

```
oJob = Popen('sudo python mypgm.py',shell=True, creationflags = subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP)
```

[source](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects)

> subprocess.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP
>   A Popen creationflags parameter to specify that a new process group will be created. This flag is necessary for using os.kill() on the subprocess.

**EDIT** I agree with the comment on how to import stuff and why you are getting something is undefined. Also the other answer seems to be on the right track getting the pid

```
import subprocess as sub

oJob = sub.Popen('sudo python mypgm.py', creationflags = sub.CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP)
oJob.kill()
```

> Warning Executing shell commands that incorporate unsanitized input from an untrusted source makes a program vulnerable to shell injection, a serious security flaw which can result in arbitrary command execution. For this reason, the use of `shell=True` is strongly discouraged in cases where the command string is constructed from external input:

Comment: I'm using "from subprocess import *" and it's saying subprocess not defined

Comment: Then you've already imported CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP into the global namespace. However, you shouldn't be using `from subprocess import *` anyway. Use either `import subprocess` or specify just those names you want to import. E.g., `from subprocess import Popen, CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP`.

Comment: @Rod Yes this should work on a pi. This is the built in subprocess module. Any standard python release will have it.

Comment: AttributeError 'module' object has no attribute named CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP

Comment: @Rod, `creationflags` is a Windows thing.

Answer (score 1):

When you add the option `shell=True`, python launches a shell and the shell in turn launches the process `python mymgm.py`. You are killing the shell process here which doesn't kill its own child that runs mymgm.py.

To ensure, that child process gets killed on `oJob.kill`, you need to group them all under one process group and make shell process, the group leader. 
The code is,

```
import os
import signal
import subprocess

# The os.setsid() is passed in the argument preexec_fn so
# it's run after the fork() and before  exec() to run the shell.
pro = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                       shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setsid) 

os.killpg(pro.pid, signal.SIGTERM)  # Send the signal to all the process groups
```

When you send `SIGTERM` signal to the shell process, it will kill all its child process as well.

Comment: Maybe true, maybe not. Some shells automatically exec the last command in the string they're invoked with.